# Liquidity Pool Smart Contract

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

Can we add a new asset to a liquidity pool?
For example, I have a lp with token A and B and I want to add a new asset token C. Is it possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't add a third asset to an typical liquidity pool, because a liquidity pool is essentially a smart contract that holds a pair of erc20 tokens, where you can trade one token for another.

In order to create a liquidity pool for the C token, you must pair it with another token against which you want to trade. For example, you can create a A/C, or B/C trading pair as a new pool contract on Uniswap V2. Then the Uniswap router will handle the conversion between A, B and C.